# Make HTTP request to web API using regular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, https

I am trying to access a php script on a server that returns a JSON object. I am trying to do this with pure JS (not jQuery or React).

I have the following JS:

```
//Define Parameters:
var param1 = document.getElementById("param1");
var param2 = document.getElementById("param2");

//Send data to the server:
function sendData() {

    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //On Success:
    XHR.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        alert(event.target.responseText);
    });

    //On Fail:
    XHR.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
        alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
    });

    //Setup the request:
    XHR.open("POST", "https://www.example.com/folder/file.php");
    XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    //Perform the request:
    XHR.send(JSON.stringify({
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2
    }));

}
```

These parameters are inputted from a HTML page by the user. It seams that the request is not sending to POST parameters and the `request type` is `OPTIONS` not `POST`.

**EDIT 1:**

As suggested in the comments, I have tried a fetch request and the request is working. It does not appear to be passing my POST parameters through. My code is as follows.

```
//Define Parameters:
var param1 = document.getElementById("param1");
var param2 = document.getElementById("param2");

var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
formData.append('param1', param1);
formData.append('param2', param2);

//Send data to the server:
function sendData() {

    var url = 'https://www.example.com/folder/file.php';

    fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers:{
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `fetch` more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @SGhaleb I have changed to a fetch request but It does not seem to be passing my parameters to my script as I am now receiving what should be received when the user types in the wrong credentials. I will edit my answer to reflect my new code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `headers` section in your `fetch` request so that the defaults are used instead.

Comment: I tried to remove the headers, same issue. The parameters are not being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see that the right type of data is being sent in the fetch request? The wrong type being received in a field can mess with the results you see. What errors are you receiving?
This link may also describe something you're running into on the fetch:
https://stanko.github.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

(This really should be a comment, but I don't have the reputation for that, sorry).

Comment: There is no error code. The request is being completed successfully but the parameters are not passing to the PHP.